# How to work PAM8304 with ESP32?

Tags: audio

I want to operate the speaker using the PAM8304 IC with ESP32. I am using arduino codes to do this. I researched many sites. I could only find codes related to PAM8302. (Library I use: XT_DAC_Audio) However, I could not make my speaker work with this library. Only crackling sound comes from my speaker. (The OUT+ pin of the PAM8304 IC is connected to the DAC pin of the esp32). Is there a library you can recommend me to run PAM8304?

Comment: What did your circuit and interconnections and power supply look like schematically? Have you read the data sheets to explore what the coding differences might be?

Comment: The DAC should presumably be connected (via a LPF) to the amp's input, not output.